# Trigger.isBefore throwing a NPE in if statement

Tags: apex, trigger, exception

I ran the following code in anonymous apex:

```
System.debug('Value of Trigger.isBefore: ' + Trigger.isBefore);
if (Trigger.isBefore) { System.debug('In is before trigger.'); }
```

Line 1 prints:

> "Value of Trigger.isBefore: null"

Line 2 throws a NPE:

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

I am curious as to why Line 1 is not throwing the exception if there's one caused by `Trigger.isBefore`?

I modified the if statement from line 2 like so:

```
if (Trigger.isBefore == true) { System.debug('In is before trigger.'); }
```

Now the above if statement no longer throws a NPE. Does anybody know why I am witnessing this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In all contexts, `Trigger` itself always exists. However, when `Trigger.isExecuting` is false, all other context variables are null. It's acceptable to `String.valueOf` a null value (it outputs `null`). However, you can't have a null condition when a Boolean condition is expected, for example, `while` or `if`.

Consider the following code:

```
Boolean flag;
System.debug(''+flag); // "null"
System.debug(String.valueOf(flag)); // also "null"
if(flag) {
  System.debug('Flag is true');
}
```

This code will also throw a `NullPointerException` on the `if` statement, because `flag` is null, even though the debug statement works just fine.

When you add the equality operator to compare null to true:

```
Boolean flag;
System.debug(''+flag); // "null"
System.debug(String.valueOf(flag)); // also "null"
if(flag == true) {
  System.debug('Flag is true');
}
```

You get the comparison result of `false`, and no `NullPointerException` is thrown.

Comment: Excellent response, that makes sense now!